# Use HttpWebRequest object within WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, asmx, webmethod

I'm trying to use the `HttpWebRequest` object within a `Webmethod`, but I get the design time error `Type 'HttpWebRequest' is not defined.`

How can I fix this?

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class geolocation
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetCities(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.mytesturl.com")
    'on this line I get: Type 'HttpWebRequest' is not defined (first HttpWebRequest)

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: in which context are you running that method?

Comment: Updated my post....that's what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

try to create the web request from a given url:

```
Dim sUri As String = "yourURL"
Dim myUri As System.Uri = New System.Uri(sUri)
Dim HttpWRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri)
```

Edit:
and don't forget to add the reference of Namespace: System.Net Assembly: System (in System.dll) in your project

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work since I can't define a variable of type HttpWebRequest.

Comment: have you added system.net as a reference in your project?

Comment: Namespace:  System.Net
Assembly:  System (in System.dll)